# Symfony2: how can I load a user taking into account its mapping entity?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Although I'm using Symfony 2.1 with FOSUserBundle and everything works perfectly, I don't know how I can resolve a problem.

Basically, I would like to know if there is a way to find (load or get) a user from the database taking into account a relationship with another entity.

This is the situation:

I have made that users can also login into my site thru a social network (Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, etc). I besides ask them for an offline access, so I can access their social accounts any time.

As each user can have as many connections as they want (or maybe none cause they are optionals), I've decided not to save this information in the user table. I've created an abstract entity called "SocialConnection" which is extended by the real ones (Google, Facebook, ect). In this entity I store the user information that I get when the user logs in my site thru those networks (user_id, social_id, access_token, etc), so in my User class I have mapped a collection of the abstract "SocialEngine" that allows me to have all networks together.

In order to be able to add others networks like Twitter, Yahoo and so on in the future, I think it is the way it should be.

So, the problem now is that when the user logs into my site thru any of these social networks I need to load him from the database knowing his social id, but I don't know how to do it.

I've seen that the method $this->findUserBy of UserManager find a user regarding a property but I think this is not the case.

What should I do to find a nice solution?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Izzy.

Comment: No time to dig deeper, however this might help https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/issues/145 and http://blog.finger-spiele.de/2012/06/20/symfony-2-merge-accounts-automatically-with-fosuserbundle-fosfacebookbundle/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I forgot to tell I'm using HWIOAuthBundle, and like FOSFacebookBundle also does, they save the social Id in the user entity which means I have to add a social id property for each social network. In my case this not only implicates those fields but also the ones for offline access (access token, refresh token, token secret, etc).I have it working like this with no problem, but I'd like to do something more dynamic and clean. Thanks again!

Comment: I am looking forward for a solutions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to get deeper into doctrine's api. The base repositories methods (find, findBy etc...) won't be enough.

You need to use [doctrine's DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html). It looks like SQL but you query based on your mapping metadata and not based on the database schema directly.

If your User has a `OneToMany` `$socialAccounts` property to the `SocialEngine`. You will be able to do something like:

```
SELECT u
FROM Bundle:User AS u
JOIN u.socialAccounts AS sa
WHERE sa.id = 34
```

But you can only query on SocialEngine's properties, not on the subclasses one ... (ie: You can't query on a SocialFacebookEngine's `facebookId`).

You either have to put all the twitter/facebook/etc data in the base `SocialEngine` class, on in the `User` class.
Or you could create an entity for each "Social Engine", and create a OneToOne relation relation between each of theses engines and the User.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I found a solution extending the User Manager of FOSUserBundle and adding a method that loads users thru your connections account. However, your answer not only helped me a lot but also it is a nice solution to this problem. Thanks again!